# Converting color hex numbers with leading zeros to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I'm using a canvas library that requires the colors to be declared in hex number format (e.g. **0x0000FF**) but I'm using a jQuery plugin for color inputs that receives the colors in string format ("*#0000FF*").

I'm using `color.toString(16)` to get the color number as a string - don't worry about the # - but when the color has leading zeros like in the example value I get "ff" and the color input doesn't work properly.

I need it to be `"0000ff"` but I don't know how to make a generic solution that works for colors with or without leading zeros. What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Just zero pad it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`String#padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) function to add `0` until your string has a length of 6 characters.

```js
const color = 0x0000FF;

console.log(color.toString(16).padStart(6, '0'));
```

Comment: Thanks! I know it was simple but didn't know the proper way to do it.